# Toggle temperature value Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I would like to toggle back and forth with a click on temperature, I have tried some ways back I get 'too much recursion' error. Works when I am switching to Kelvin, but can't figure out how to switch back to Celsius. Any help appreciated.

This is my html:

```
<p style="cursor: pointer">Temperature: <span id="temperature" class="toggle"></span></p>
```

And here's the javascript:

```
var tempKelvin = data.main.temp;
var tempCelsius = Math.round(((data.main.temp) - 273.15));

$("#temperature").html(tempCelsius + 'C');

$("#temperature").click(function(){
    $(".toggle").html(Math.round(tempKelvin) + 'K');
});
```

Comment: The recursion error is happening outside of the code you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

try this.....

```
var tempKelvin = data.main.temp;
var tempCelsius = Math.round(((data.main.temp) - 273.15));

$("#temperature").html(tempCelsius + 'C');

$("#temperature").click(function(){
if ($(".toggle").html().indexOf('K')==-1)
{
    $(".toggle").html(Math.round(tempKelvin) + 'K');
}

else
{
$("#temperature").html(tempCelsius + 'C');
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd keep whether to show Kelvin or Celcius in a variable, something like:

```js
var temp = 290;
var tempKelvin = temp;
var tempCelsius = Math.round(((temp) - 273.15));

$("#temperature").html(tempCelsius + 'C');

var showKelvin = false;

$("#temperature").click(function(){
  showKelvin = !showKelvin;
  if (showKelvin) {
    $("#temperature").html(Math.round(tempKelvin) + 'K');
  } else {
    $("#temperature").html(tempCelsius + 'C');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="cursor: pointer">Temperature: <span id="temperature" ></span></p>
```

You don't need the toggle class - you can just use the temprature id in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply have another variable to track which temperature is displayed.

See example below as per [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z6kcvp1h/)

```
var data = {main: {temp: 500}};
var tempKelvin = data.main.temp;
var tempCelsius = Math.round(((data.main.temp) - 273.15));
var celcius = true;

$("#temperature").html(tempCelsius + 'C');

$("#temperature").click(function(){
    if (celcius) {
        $(".toggle").html(Math.round(tempKelvin) + 'K');
    } else {
      $("#temperature").html(tempCelsius + 'C');
    }
    celcius = !celcius;
});
```

Comment: could you just briefly explain what exactly celcius = !celcius; does?

Comment: It changes the value for the opposite. So if it is `true` it turns it into `false` and if it is `false` it turns it into `true`.

Answer (score 1):

I recently worked on a similar challenge, in the FreeCodeCamp curriculum. This was my solution.

```
        var temp = 25;
        var celsius = temp;
        var fahr = (1.8 * temp + 32);
        var switch_ = new Boolean(false);

        $("#toggle").on("click", function() {
            switch_ = !switch_;
            var temp = switch_ == true ? celsius + " °C" : fahr + " °F";
            $(this).text(temp);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
 var tempKelvin = 10;
 var tempCelsius = Math.round(((tempKelvin) - 273.15));
 
 function toggleTemp(){
  var temp = $("#temperature").data("temp");
  if(temp == "celsius") {
   $("#temperature").text(tempKelvin + "K");
   $("#temperature").data("temp", "kelvin");
  } else {
   $("#temperature").text(tempCelsius + "C");
   $("#temperature").data("temp", "celsius");
  }
 }
 
 $(document).ready(function(){
  toggleTemp();
  
  $("#temperature").click(function(){
   toggleTemp();
  });
 });
</script>

<p style="cursor: pointer">Temperature: <span id="temperature" class="toggle" data-temp="kelvin"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this HTML

```
<a href="#" id="toggle">temp</a>
```

And this JS

```
        var temp = 25;
        var celsius = temp;
        var fahr = (1.8 * temp + 32);
        var switch_ = new Boolean(false);

        $("#toggle").on("click", function() {
            switch_ = !switch_;
            var temp = switch_ == true ? celsius + " °C" : fahr + " °F";
            $(this).text(temp);
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

**Use this it will solve your problem.**

HTML :

```
<p style="cursor: pointer">
    Temperature: 
    <span id="tempKelvin" class="toggle"></span>
    <span id="tempCelsius" class="toggle" style="display:none"></span>
</p>
```

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var tempKelvin = data.main.temp;
     var tempCelsius = Math.round((tempKelvin - 273.15));

     $("#tempKelvin").text(tempKelvin + 'K');
     $("#tempCelsius").text(tempCelsius + 'C');

     $("p").click(function(){
         $("span").toggle();
     }); 
});
```